# Conditional Variance

Tags: statistics

I'm having a bit of trouble conceptualising the step which i have highlighted.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall the variance of the sum of *independent* random variables:
$$
    \mathbf{Var}(Y_1+Y_2 + \cdots + Y_n) =  \mathbf{Var}(Y_1)+\mathbf{Var}(Y_2) + \cdots + \mathbf{Var}(Y_n)
$$
Now is these independent random variables are identically distributed, $ \mathbf{Var}(Y_1)=  \mathbf{Var}(Y_2) = \ldots =  \mathbf{Var}(Y_n) = \sigma^2$.

The conditional variance $\mathbf{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^X Y_i \mid X\right)$ means variance of the sum for a fixed values of $X$, making the above calculation immediately applicable.